# How to rotate the label such that its base line is parallel to the bisector?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

How to rotate the label counter clockwise such that its base line is parallel to the bisector?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polyline](1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstBissectBAC[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}{C'}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.5,LabelSep=0.75]{A}{B}{C}{\tiny$180^\circ-\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polyline](1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstBissectBAC[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{A}{B}{C}{B'}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.6,LabelSep=1]{A}{B}{C}{}
    \pcline[linestyle=none](B')(B)\ncput[nrot=:U,npos=0.84]{\tiny$180^\circ-\theta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

a solution without knowing `B'`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polyline](1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.6,LabelSep=1]{A}{B}{C}{}
  \pcline[linestyle=none](!
    \psGetNodeCenter{A} \psGetNodeCenter{B} \psGetNodeCenter{C}      
    /LengthBA B.x A.x sub dup mul B.y A.y sub dup mul add sqrt def     
    /LengthBC C.x A.x sub dup mul C.y A.y sub dup mul add sqrt def     
    /Factor LengthBC LengthBA div def     
    A.x B.x sub Factor mul B.x add /A.x ED     
    A.y B.y sub Factor mul B.y add /A.y ED     
    A.x C.x add 2 div A.y C.y add 2 div )(B)\ncput[nrot=:U,npos=0.84]{\tiny$180^\circ-\theta$} 
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It becomes more complicated :-)

Comment: no, because you do not need any coodinate

Comment: I meant that your solution depends on `B'` while my solution does not. However, I cannot rotate the label clockwise.

Comment: no I do not need the B'. I used it only while it was defined. See edit for another solution

Comment: The calculation in the second example will put the label on the median rather than on the angle bisector.

Comment: I edit the last example

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution even though it is not elegant enough.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polyline](1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.6,LabelSep=1]{A}{B}{C}{\rput{(B)}(0,0){\tiny$180^\circ-\theta$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Clockwise rotation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](6,6)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polyline](1,1){A}(5,5){B}(4,1){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.6,LabelSep=1]{A}{B}{C}{\rput{!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x atan 180 sub}(0,0){\tiny$180^\circ-\theta$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```