# How to pass a node as the angle argument of \uput?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I am attempting to solve my own problem [How to rotate the label such that its base line is parallel to the bisector?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65668/9467) with the most elegant approach, i.e., passing a node as an angle argument of `\uput`.

The following cases are ordered from the less elegant (but successful) to the more elegant (but fail).

- Case 1: Success to pass literal constants.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-eucl}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
      \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline]
          (1,1){O}
          (2,3){A}
      \pstGeonode([nodesep=2]O){X}
      \psline[linestyle=dashed](O)(X)
      \psarc[origin={O},linecolor=red]{->}(O){0.5}{(X)}{(A)}
      \uput{1}%
      [
          !3 1 sub 2 1 sub atan
      ]
      {
          !3 1 sub 2 1 sub atan
      }(O){\textcolor{red}{$\pi-\theta$}}
  \end{pspicture}

  \end{document}
  ```
- Case 2: Fail to use `\psGetNodeCenter`.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-eucl}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
      \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline]
          (1,1){O}
          (2,3){A}
      \pstGeonode([nodesep=2]O){X}
      \psline[linestyle=dashed](O)(X)
      \psarc[origin={O},linecolor=red]{->}(O){0.5}{(X)}{(A)}
      \uput{1}%
      [
          !\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub A.x O.x sub atan 
      ]
      {
          !\psGetNodeCenter{A}\psGetNodeCenter{O} A.y O.y sub A.x O.x sub atan
      }(O){\textcolor{red}{$\pi-\theta$}}
  \end{pspicture}


  \end{document}
  ```
- Case 3: Fail to pass a node.

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-eucl}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
      \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90},CurveType=polyline]
          (1,1){O}
          (2,3){A}
      \pstGeonode([nodesep=2]O){X}
      \psline[linestyle=dashed](O)(X)
      \psarc[origin={O},linecolor=red]{->}(O){0.5}{(X)}{(A)}
      \uput{1}[(A)]{(A)}(O){\textcolor{red}{$\pi-\theta$}}
  \end{pspicture}    

  \end{document}
  ```

How to pass a node as the angle argument of `\uput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,90}](1,1){O}(2,3){A}
    \pstGeonode([nodesep=2]O){X}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](O)(X)
    \psarc[origin={O},linecolor=red]{->}(O){0.5}{(X)}{(A)}
    \pcline(O)(A)\ncput*[nrot=:U]{\textcolor{red}{$\pi-\theta$}}
\end{pspicture}    

\end{document}
```

[image]